# I need to create a function that takes a vector of strings, then sorts them by their last letter

Tags: c++

I was thinking of modifying quicksort to work with strings, but I doubt that would work, even if I knew how to do that.

Comment: Is this homework?  If not, use standard library sorting functions, and pass in a comparison for your strings.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use the standard algorithms:

```
void sortIt(std::vector<std::string>& v) {
    std::sort(begin(v), end(v), [](auto&& a, auto&& b) {
        return a.back() < b.back(); });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy one:

1. Create a `compare` function to order two strings according to their last letter;
2. call `std::sort` on the string vector.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

const struct
{
    bool operator() (const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const
    {   
        // care, would throw on an empty string.
        const char lastA = a.at(a.length() - 1);
        const char lastB = b.at(b.length() - 1);
        return lastA < lastB;
    }
} lastCharLess;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> strings = {
        "world", "kebab", "abracadabra", "frolic" };
    std::sort(strings.begin(), strings.end(), lastCharLess);
    for (auto&& s : strings)
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
abracadabra
kebab
frolic
world
```

Comment: You aren't actually doing what you say, but that's better. Still, curious that you create a global object of unnamed type. Anyway, if you can use `auto` or for-range-loops, you have lambdas. Also, prefer using `auto&&` unless you really have to be more specific. And the `return 0;` is implicit... All in all, have an upvote.

Comment: I agree on everything, unless the implicit `return 0`. I dislike implicit things in C++. The more explicit, the more easy to read, the less error prone.